# How i can secure c# program

Tags: c#

2 months before i started learning c# programming.

When I started I knew program can be decompiled, that is only problem about me and c#.
I have question, how i can secure my code, I know i can obfuscate code with other programs. But i don't like to do that, because i knew there is program that can deobfuscate obfuscated program.

**1.** When I write line like `connectionString = "... password: mypassword id: myid"`
how I can secure that line, I want no one to have access to that line when someone decompile my program.

**2.** same like 1. one. How I can secure program, a program that needs a password to enter the main part, someone can just decompile program and remove the password and open main part directly.

Sorry if question is stupid, please don't dislike, I am new, I didn't found question like this.

Comment: basically: **you can't**. you can only make it _more secure_ by obfuscation. but you can't make it _completely_ secure. and if your conne(c)tionString is so secret, _don't put it in your code_. simple as that. you shouldn't do that, anyway, but use a configuration file.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Yes, but how i can secure my connection to database from this, how big companies do that?

Than c# is not for big programs?

Comment: You either use integrated security in the database so there is no need for a password or you perform sensitive work on an external service which the user has to authenticate to. It is too big a question for an answer here.

Comment: Big companies, small companies, anyone who knows what they are doing do not write applications that contain secret passwords.  So, your architectural approach is wrong.

Comment: @LiveMomentS it's simple: they don't let the _program_ know the credentials. either the _user_ has valid credentials and can access the DB, or he doesn't. plus: client-programs _rarely_ ever access a DB directly, but an API-service instead.

Comment: @MikeNakis yes but how can someone connect program to sql database without writing connect with name and password of database ?

Comment: I did not say you can connect to a database without a user name and a password.  I said that it cannot be a secret.  Revise your entire approach until it does not require a password which is secret from the person using it.

Comment: @aepot I like this answer, you can answer question, I will like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real approach is using **Server**.

Client application represents the client itself. All the app knows, client knows. Then the server may be a bridge between the database and client and give the client only required permissions to access the data.

You may introduce some API server into your architecture. That's the easiest approach: only server will know the password.

The most popular way of implementation is REST API with JSON as data format.